# Conda install FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, conda

I am getting the below error while attempting conda install commands (for instance while attempting geopandas install)

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::attrs-20.3.0-pyhd3deb0d_0'.
FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
```

Please can someone help?

Comment: Can you update the question to show the exact command you used?

Answer (score 0):

Update your conda with `conda update conda --yes`

Also in this issue of conda repository from Github some people have the same problem check this out:
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9761